# Find a row in a data frame including columns with NA's?

Tags: r, dataframe, find, match

I have a translation table with 67 columns and I get an input of 67 columns.
My goal is to check if I can find it within this translation table.

To be clear, 67 columns build a key, and additional 10 are the actual values for this key.

Please advise how can I quickly find it if some of the columns (variables) in the input can be with NA value?

small example:

input:

```
        a b  c  d  e
        1 9 "r" NA NA
```

translation table:

```
                   a b  c   d  e
                   5 NA NA  NA 9
                   6 9 "o"  4  3
                   1 9 "r"  NA NA
```

Comment: Try `which(do.call(paste, df2) %in% do.call(paste, df1))`

Comment: @akrun  What is df1 and what is df2 in your case?

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?

Comment: I meant the input as 'df1' data.frame' and the transition table as 'df2'.  Here, we are pasting the rows of each data.frame to create a vector of strings and then check whether it is %in% the other vector

Comment: @akrun please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Thank you.  I posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `paste` method to create a string for each row in both datasets and then with `%in%` get a logical `vector` indicating the string is contained in the other vector.  Wrapping with `which` gives the position of the rows where this is `TRUE`

```
which(do.call(paste, df2) %in% do.call(paste, df1))
```